# windowDidLoad windowWillLoad on NSWindowController never called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I am creating a window using the following code:

```
if(hudWindow == nil)
    hudWindow = [[TimelogWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"TimelogWindow" owner: self];
[hudWindow showWindow: self];
```

the window displays correctly, however the TimelogWindowController's windowDidLoad and windowWillLoad methods are never called. I have set te delegate, what else could be the problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really mean `self` (it is not clear from your code what exactly is `self`) to be the owner of TimelogWindow.nib? It is usually the window controller that’s the owner of the nib file. Try replacing

```
hudWindow = [[TimelogWindowController alloc]
    initWithWindowNibName:@"TimelogWindow" owner: self];
```

with

```
hudWindow = [[TimelogWindowController alloc]
    initWithWindowNibName:@"TimelogWindow"];
```

so that the newly created `TimelogWindowController` instance becomes the owner of that nib file, make sure File’s Owner in TimelogWindow.nib is set as of type `TimelogWindowController`, and that File’s Owner `window` outlet is connected to the window object.

Comment: Also, try using `[hudWindow.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];` instead of `[hudWindow showWindow:self];`